# Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /script.php on this server. (but only sometimes)

Tags: php, iis, permissions

I have a web application that my clients deploy on IIS servers. One particular client has an issue where they get a `Forbidden:  You don't have permission to access /script.php on this server.` error. When they try to access `script.php`

The trouble is that `script.php` is called many times in my application and it is only in one part of my application (a form submit) that i get the above error . In all other instances it works.

Any ideas why this this error would appear? what is it i need to check?

Comment: what do the logs say?

Comment: if u mean the php logs, no errors of any kind

Comment: how about the server logs?

Comment: it only logs successful post/get requests and an odd 500 error. no 403's

Comment: Is the verb POST allowed (as far as your form tries to post data)?

Comment: Yes it is. POSTS have occured many times in this application

Comment: What kind of PHP integration on IIS? ISAPI or FastCGI?

Comment: FastCGI is what is used

Comment: If this is still an issue, can you show the code for the page(s) calling script.php?

Comment: @Martin no it turned out to be a firewall issue